# Can not install libuiohook in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, installation

I'm trying to install libuiohook in windows 7, but I'm having problems.

Firts I installed all the dependencies: autotools, pkg-config, libtool, gcc, clang or msys2/mingw32 (I couldn't install clang but I have msys)

In the instrucctions for installing libuiohook I must do:

./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make && make install

When I run ./bootstrap.sh I'm getting this log that have a lot of warnings:

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext 
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4 --output=aclocal.m4t
autoreconf: `aclocal.m4' is unchanged
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_static_works, ...): susp
icious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2013: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2026: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:1383: AC_LIBTOOL_LINKER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3214: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3118: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:995: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:853: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:833: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: the top level
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works, ...): suspici
ous cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:1351: AC_LIBTOOL_COMPILER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:5371: AC_LIBTOOL_PROG_COMPILER_PIC is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_CXX, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:3972: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3222: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:2370: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_F77, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:4204: _LT_AC_LANG_F77_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:4116: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_F77_CONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_GCJ, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:4256: _LT_AC_LANG_GCJ_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:4212: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_GCJ_CONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:102: warning: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP was called before AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_D
LL
aclocal.m4:2386: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:512: AS_CASE is expanded from...
configure.ac:102: the top level
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
Putting files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `config'.
autoreconf: running: /usr/local/bin/autoconf --force
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_static_works, ...): susp
icious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2013: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2026: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:1383: AC_LIBTOOL_LINKER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3214: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3118: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:995: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:853: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:833: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: the top level
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works, ...): suspici
ous cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:1351: AC_LIBTOOL_COMPILER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:5371: AC_LIBTOOL_PROG_COMPILER_PIC is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_CXX, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:3972: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3222: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:2370: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_F77, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:4204: _LT_AC_LANG_F77_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:4116: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_F77_CONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_GCJ, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:4256: _LT_AC_LANG_GCJ_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:4212: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_GCJ_CONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:102: warning: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP was called before AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_D
LL
aclocal.m4:2386: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:512: AS_CASE is expanded from...
configure.ac:102: the top level
autoreconf: running: /usr/local/bin/autoheader --force
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_static_works, ...): susp
icious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2013: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2026: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:1383: AC_LIBTOOL_LINKER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3214: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3118: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:995: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:853: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:833: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: the top level
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works, ...): suspici
ous cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:1351: AC_LIBTOOL_COMPILER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:5371: AC_LIBTOOL_PROG_COMPILER_PIC is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_CXX, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:3972: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3222: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:2370: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_F77, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:4204: _LT_AC_LANG_F77_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:4116: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_F77_CONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_GCJ, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:4256: _LT_AC_LANG_GCJ_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:4212: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_GCJ_CONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:102: warning: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP was called before AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_D
LL
aclocal.m4:2386: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:512: AS_CASE is expanded from...
configure.ac:102: the top level
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_static_works, ...): susp
icious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2013: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2026: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:1383: AC_LIBTOOL_LINKER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3214: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3118: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:995: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:853: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:833: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: the top level
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works, ...): suspici
ous cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:1351: AC_LIBTOOL_COMPILER_OPTION is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:5371: AC_LIBTOOL_PROG_COMPILER_PIC is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_CXX, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:3972: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:3222: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:2370: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_F77, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:4204: _LT_AC_LANG_F77_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:4116: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_F77_CONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:76: warning: AC_CACHE_VAL(lt_prog_compiler_pic_works_GCJ, ...): sus
picious cache-id, must contain _cv_ to be cached
aclocal.m4:4256: _LT_AC_LANG_GCJ_CONFIG is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:4212: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_GCJ_CONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:102: warning: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP was called before AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_D
LL
aclocal.m4:2386: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:512: AS_CASE is expanded from...
configure.ac:102: the top level
libuiohook_la_LDFLAGS: variable `LTLDFLAGS' is used but `LTLDFLAGS' is undefined

Makefile.am: C objects in subdir but `AM_PROG_CC_C_O' not in `configure.ac'
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

But this it's the error I'm getting

```
libuiohook_la_LDFLAGS: variable `LTLDFLAGS' is used but `LTLDFLAGS' is undefined

Makefile.am: C objects in subdir but `AM_PROG_CC_C_O' not in `configure.ac'
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

Comment: I suppose libiohook. right? Maybe if you add the keywords C, C++ and libiohook you could attract more attention

Comment: Yeah that's right, thanks for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the way to install it on windows, if anyone ever needs too they can do it by following the steps in this link:

[Libuiohook installation step by step](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Compiling)

Comment: Although the link might answer the question consider adding the relevant information as part of your answer

Comment: Sure, but what do you mean with relevant information.